# Printopia (AirPrint): turn it on/off via command line?

Tags: command-line, airprint

I love Printopia - this allows my iDevices to print to a printer attached to my Mac. The problem is I usually don't leave it on all the time. Whenever I want to print from my phone, I'd turn it on via System Preferences app.

Question: is it possible to do so via command line? This way I can ssh in my Mac and turn it on/off (or even better, write some simple script to automate the process).

Answer (score 3):

There's no real reason that I can think of *not* to leave it on all of the time, but you can easily turn it on and off by loading or unloading the launchd plist:

This will turn it on:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ecamm.printopia.plist`

This will turn it off:

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ecamm.printopia.plist`

Or you could just run the server directly:

`/Library/PreferencePanes/Printopia.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Printopia Server.app/Contents/MacOS/Printopia Server`

(that's all one line)